Origin in this script not being updated. Any help appreciated
I have tried to copy CodeMonkey's tutorial on a field of view script from YouTube, however, the origin of the raycasts is not updating to the player's position. What is working correctly is the direction of the raycasts but not the position as it still thinks it is at 0, 0. I can attach the field of view script to my player controller to move the mesh but the problem remains. I have tried debugging through printing the position of the origin and it does move with the player's coordinates apparently but is not calculating correctly still. I have an object the script is colliding with properly but once the player moves, the raycast 'hits' don't update making it seem like the object is still there. This is in Unity 2D.
Here is the script:
public class FieldOfView : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask layerMask;

    private Mesh mesh;
    //create mesh
    private float fov;
    private Vector3 origin;
    private float startingAngle;
    private void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        fov = 90f;
        origin = Vector3.zero;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 origin = Vector3.zero;
        int rayCount = 100;
        float angle = startingAngle;
        float angleIncrease = fov / rayCount;
        float viewDistance = 10f;

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[rayCount + 1 + 1];
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
        int[] triangles = new int[rayCount * 3];

        vertices[0] = origin;

        int vertexIndex = 1;
        int triangleIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rayCount; i++)
        {


            Vector3 vertex = origin + GetVectorFromAngle(angle) * viewDistance;
            RaycastHit2D raycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(origin, GetVectorFromAngle(angle), viewDistance, layerMask);
            if (raycastHit2D.collider == null)
            {
                // did not hit
                vertex = origin + GetVectorFromAngle(angle) * viewDistance;
            }
            else
            {
                // object hit
                vertex = raycastHit2D.point;
            }
            vertices[vertexIndex] = vertex;

            if (i > 0)
            {

                triangles[triangleIndex + 0] = 0;
                triangles[triangleIndex + 1] = vertexIndex - 1;
                triangles[triangleIndex + 2] = vertexIndex;

                triangleIndex += 3;
            }

            vertexIndex++;
            angle -= angleIncrease;

        }

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.uv = uv;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
    }

    public void SetOrigin(Vector3 origin)
    {

        this.origin = origin;

    }

    public void SetAimDirection(Vector3 aimDirection)
    {
        startingAngle = GetAngleFromVectorFloat(aimDirection) + fov / 2f;
    }

    public static Vector3 GetVectorFromAngle(float angle)
    {
        float angleRad = angle * (Mathf.PI / 180f);
        return new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angleRad), Mathf.Sin(angleRad));
    }

    public static float GetAngleFromVectorFloat(Vector3 dir)
    {
        dir = dir.normalized;
        float n = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        if (n < 0) n += 360;

        return n;
    }
    
}

This is the PlayerAim script where this is called
public class PlayerAim : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private FieldOfView fieldOfView;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
        Vector3 aimDir = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized;
        fieldOfView.SetAimDirection(aimDir);
        fieldOfView.SetOrigin(transform.position);
    }

   
    

    public static Vector3 GetMouseWorldPosition()
    {
        Vector3 vec = GetMouseWorldPositionWithZ(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main);
        vec.z = 0f;
        return vec;
    }

    public static Vector3 GetMouseWorldPositionWithZ()
    {
        return GetMouseWorldPositionWithZ(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main);
    }

    public static Vector3 GetMouseWorldPositionWithZ(Camera worldCamera)
    {
        return GetMouseWorldPositionWithZ(Input.mousePosition, worldCamera);
    }

    public static Vector3 GetMouseWorldPositionWithZ(Vector3 screenPosition, Camera worldCamera)
    {
        Vector3 worldPosition = worldCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);
        return worldPosition;
    }

    public static Vector3 GetDirToMouse(Vector3 fromPosition)
    {
        Vector3 mouseWorldPosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
        return (mouseWorldPosition - fromPosition).normalized;
    }


}

Apoligies if my wording is ambiguious, I am a beginner to coding. Again, any help appreciated.

Everything in the LateUpdate function is working with a local variable named origin, not the member variable. As far as I can tell that is never used by anything but the SetOrigin function. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Vector3 origin = Vector3.zero; you probably want to remove this line from LateUpdate

@Retired Ninja I have attempted to copy it exactly but have gotten errors such as in the PlayerAim script the Vector3 aimDir = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized; line should be Vector3 aimDir = (targetPosition - vObject.GetPosition).normalized;

@derHugo When I remove that line of code, the mesh moves at twice the speed of my player for some reason but still calculates as if the origin is at 0, 0 could be a step in the right direction.

well you set SetOrigin(transform.position) ... the Mesh.vertices are in LOCAL SPACE but you pass in some world space position based on origin + ... and also some world space hit point ... hard to tell what you are even trying to achieve tbh
